# Trying to debug postTweet with thujohn Twitter API for Laravel

Tags: php, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

This line of code **was** working fine but now it is not.

```
Twitter::postTweet(array('status' => "test tweet", 'format' => 'json'));
```

How do I get the response from Twitter? Or figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Response for twitter will be probably the result of this function, so you need to use:

```
$twitterResponse = Twitter::postTweet(array('status' => "test tweet", 'format' => 'json'));
```

You probably use [this Twitter Api](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4)

Comment: I've tried that and when I `var_dump($twitterResponse);` I get `bool(false)`

Comment: So it probably mean that this Tweet hasn't been published. You need to put into config file valid data - look at https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4/blob/master/src/config/config.php

Comment: I've done this too! It was working previously but all of a sudden it's stopped and I have no idea why or how to find out why.

Comment: @barro32 This class rather won't tell you more. You need to check if for example your IP wasn't blocked and so on